# Uncaught RangeError while triggering type file event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, file-io, contact-form-7

this is the click event code

```
function jqueryscript_in_head(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(function() {
        $j("input[type=file]").wrap("<div class='hider' style='height:0px;width:0px;' />");
        $j(".hider").wrap("<div class='fileinputimg' />");
        $j(".fileinputimg").on("click", this, function(e) {
            $j("input[type=file]").trigger('click');
        });

    });
    </script> <?php
 } add_action('wp_head', 'jqueryscript_in_head');
```

I cant get it work.. I tried it with `live() delegate() click() bind()` its all too heavy.

Its an Contact Form 7 based on WordPress.

[this is the site](http://www.sec-org.co.il/?page_id=191)
click the div under the input field at the bottom. 
I left the input visible so you can find it because its not in English.

[image]

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: ive managed to make this work with this settings
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBHmi

can someone tell why the previous setting didn't worked?